# How to create an installer for ASP.net website with NSIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, nsis

I want to create an installer for ASP.net website.
Can I use NSIS to create an installer for my web application.
So I wanted to do followings through the installation wizard.

1. I need to install required databases in client computer.
2. I need to update the connection string in web.config file based the database.
3. I need to create ODBC connection and save their names in my project    config file.
4. I need to create an application in application pool of IIS.
5. I need to host my project in IIS.

Can someone please let me know is it possible to do those things with NSIS?If possible how can I do it?
Thanking you.

Comment: Why do you need to create an installer for a website ? Isn't this usually a one-time deployment task ? Or are you shipping some sort of product ?

Comment: Yep..I am shipping my product to foreign customer..He is not familiar with technical stuff..So I need to make simple wizard to do all the configurations.

Comment: NSIS can execute methods in a custom .NET assembly, and you can create an IIS website (and app pool) from C#. Start here - http://bit.ly/1GdBfJd and here - http://bit.ly/1LYtraf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no exact answer for you.

You need to create a customized installer with custom pages - but it is up to you how the custom pages look like and what they do.

You **can** achieve this with NSIS (even with Inno Setup which is a little easier to user) but we cannot post tutorial for you.

What you need to do is to start with simple installer (default one) and add custom pages to it. It page represent some functionality:

- settings database connection values
- writing configuration
- creating app pool
- setting IIS (there are some NSIS plug-in for working with IIS)
- copying files etc.

Start with some NSIS example and add more and more functionality in it until it meets your requirements.